# Defaults of the turtle in Python turtle module

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, defaults

For teaching purposes I need a list of the graphics defaults. Here's what I have by now:

```
background  white
canvas      950W by 800H
dot         5 (pixels)
fill color  black
heading     0 (East)
home        (0,0) (screen center)
pen color   black
shape       classic (arrow)
speed       3 (of turtle)
width       1 (of line)
```

Are there any more defaults?
Thank you

Comment: Is this about python turtle?  If so, add the tags [python] and [turtle-graphics]

Comment: wibeasley, no problem. How I do that?
I did mention it in my header, though.

Comment: It looks like @cdlane added those tags for you this time.  In the future, click the 'edit' button and add those tags, just like the two your added initially (ie, [graphics] and [defaults])

Comment: I really appreciate that. Thank you @cdlane

Answer (score 2):

The `turtle.pen()` method (often confused with the `turtle.Pen()` method) allows you to query and set a number of attributes, initially showing their defaults:

```
>>> turtle.pen()
{'shown': True, 'pendown': True, 'pencolor': 'black', 'fillcolor': 'black', 'pensize': 1, 
'speed': 3, 'resizemode': 'noresize', 'stretchfactor': (1.0, 1.0),
'shearfactor': 0.0, 'outline': 1, 'tilt': 0.0}
>>>
```

Where '*shown*' is an alternate term for '*visible*'.  Other defaults:

```
mode: 'standard'  # default for turtle.mode()
colormode: 1.0  # default for turtle.colormode()
angle units: degrees  # change with turtle.radians()
```

The first two are likely screen defaults but the last is set on a per turtle basis.  I believe that this is incorrect:

```
canvas      950W by 800H
```

The default turtle screen size is 50% of your screen width and 75% of your screen height.  The screen setup routine will accept fractions as well as pixels:

```
turtle.Screen().setup(0.25, 0.25)
```

Comment: @YehudaKatz, consider accepting his answer, since it appears to [solve/answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @YehudaKatz I don't see a  green check next to this answer, but maybe something is weird with my browser's cache.  I don't see even an upvote besides mine.

Comment: wibeasley, fixed. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Canvas is the only default that is not correct. I believe that 'default' will depend on the environment you are using. For example, in trinket, the default is -200 to +200 in both the x and the y directions.

The student's I teach are complete beginners and I just stick to the ones you listed I find for most of the students that is enough.

Comment: Amber, my students are advanced learner, familiar with Python. So my needs might be different.
Good luck with your teaching.